# How to fade-in images in sequence

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling with this for a while. A client wants to have a banner fade in at the top of his site (I told him it would look lame). I have managed to get a single banner to fade in onLoad, which is great. However, he wants it to load in in stages.

For example, let's say the site is called "Apples & Pears". He wants "Apples" to fade in, followed by "&" and finally "Pears". Is this actually possible? Traditionally I would have created an animated gif or done something in Flash but these are no-nos these days, right?

So I can get all of these images to fade in onLoad but is there a way of saying "once this one has faded fully in, start the next one"?

Sorry if my asking is clunky but I think you will get what I mean!

Any help very gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ikurez/2/edit)*

Your HTML:

```
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="" alt="Apples" />
    <img src="" alt="and" />
    <img src="" alt="Pears" />
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner img{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.banner img').each(function( i ){
  $(this).delay(1000*i).fadeTo(1000,1);
});
```

..where `i` inside the `.each()` callback returns each image's index (`0, 1, 2`)

Comment: Thanks! I *think* I understand how this works. I want the images to fade in next to each other, rather than having each replace the last, so they eventually form the entire banner "Apples & Pears". I will certainly give this a try tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndyAshwin well, than just remove `position: absolute;` from the CSS.

Comment: Okay, really sorry if I am being a total idiot here but where do I put the jQuery stuff? Does that go in the html or in the .js file? I assume the latter. Sorry but I am new to jQuery/javascript...

Comment: @AndyAshwin That's why I created a jsBin demo : Click on /jsBin/ on the upper left corner and choose download. after your html document is downloaded you'll see all you need!

Comment: I really am not a cretin, honest, but I simply cannot get this fade to work. I got rid of the display:none attribute to check the image sources were okay and they are, so I put it back in. Also, I set a height for the banner div in case that was the issue but still no joy.

I tried adding the jquery code at the botom of the "jquery.min.js" but it is a remote file and cannot be edited, so I added it to my local "jquery-1.7.min.js" which I obviously referenced in the header.

Am I missing something obvious? Sorry to be a pain...

Comment: I figured it out! I had to put the script in the actual div where the images are called. Awesome. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the images above each other and then use the `.fadeIn( [duration] [, callback] ) Returns: jQuery` function on the top image, and specify a callback function which when executed will fade in the second image and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually want the images stacked - I want them to appear alongside each other so they eventually form the entire title. I assume that is actually easier than if I wanted a stack of images sequentially replacing each other!